# Is there a way to detect one, a combination, or none of multiple boolean values in C#?

Tags: c#, boolean, combinations

I have 4 booleans and it can either be one, a combination of multiple, or none. My ultimate output would be, that I know which bools are set to true.

For example: **only** one / **only** one and two / **only** one, two and three / **all** one, two , three, four / **only** two and three /  and so on..

I started out by writing these out manually using If - statements but then I started realizing: 1: this code looks very confusing. 2: this method will take a lot of effort 3. there must be a better way to do this, right?

Comment: Have you considered switching to a [flag enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=netcore-3.1) or are you constrained to booleans?

Comment: if you have a *collection* of `booleans`, say `bool[] booleans` you can use *Linq* to query: `if (booleans.All(x => x)) {...}` or `if (booleans.Count(x => x) == 1) {...}`

Comment: What is the ultimate output though? Any solution offering would be targeted to that because you seem to be saying that `if(b1&&b2)` would do something different to `if(b2&&b3)` so it's not just about the number of bools that are true

Comment: It's a little unclear what you want here. Is it enough to just count the number of true values, if its equal to the length It's all, if its 0 is none, everything else is a combination of multiple.

Comment: Thank you for all your replies! My ultimate output would be, that I know which bools are set to true :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a *collection* of booleans, e.g.

```
 bool[] flags = new bool[] {
   first,
   second,
   third,
   ...
   last 
 };
```

you can query them with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

... 

if (flags.All(x => x)) {
  // if all booleans are true 
}

if (flags.Count(x => x) == 2) {
  // if exactly two booleans are true 
} 

if (flags.Count(x => x) >= 3) {
  // if at least 3 booleans are true 
} 

if (flags.Count(x => x) <= 4) {
  // if at most 4 booleans are true 
} 

if (flags.Any(x => x)) {
  // if at least 1 boolean is true; 
  // it can be done with a help of Count, but Any is more readable 
}
```

Comment: `Any` handles only one case.  This answer addresses every case you mentioned

Comment: Please, don't call `Count` repeatedly.  `Any` and `All` are short-circuiting but `Count` is not, so you want to call it once, save the result, and then test that result multiple times..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output them with some sort of names in addition to just `bool` values as suggested by Dmitiry's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64283996/477420) add name as a text:

```
var flags = new[]
   { 
     new { Value = one,   Name = nameof(one)},
     new { Value = two,   Name = nameof(two)},
     new { Value = three, Name = nameof(three) }
   };

var trueCount = flags.Count(x => x.Value);
var names = String.Join(",", flags.Where(x => x.Value).Select(x => x.Name));

if (trueCount == 0) return $"none";
if (trueCount == 1) return $"just {names}";
else if (trueCount < flags.Length) return $"only {names}";
else return $"all {names}";
```

Note: switching to `[Flags]` enum could be useful if you want to do more than just counting true/false. Alternatively consider switching to `Dictionary<string, bool>`.